# Assigning a value to a pointer is giving error

Tags: c, clang

please tell me what’s wrong in this code, I am not able to print value 
getting segmentation fault error.

```
int main()
{
  int i=3, *p;
  p = &i+1;
  *p = 30;
  printf(“%d”, *p);
 }
```

if i use this code its working fine.

```
int main()
    {
      int i=3, *p, *q;
      q = &i;
      p = q+1;
      *p = 30;
      printf(“%d”, *p);
     }
```

Thanks for your reply

Comment: They both exhibit undefined behavior.  You're writing into memory at whatever happens to be past `i`.  Of course you're going to get unpredictable results.  It's called memory corruption, and it's a severe bug.  Don't do it.

Comment: In the first example `p = &i + 1;` means that `p` will point to the address right after the space where `i` is stored. Then you access it with `*p = 30;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should alloc memory to p, you will get random results otherwise.

Comment: This is wrong. You do not necesarely need to allocate memory! You can assign any valid address to `p` and have no undefined behaviour. For example `p = &i;` and then `*p = 30` is totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

@Olaf Dietsche had a verry good answer but since you asked the question with the given code i assume you do not quite understand the basics of pointers and the `&` operator.

Let me start with your example where you have an 'int' variable and a pointer to it:

```
int a = 10;
int* p = &a;
```

What this code does is to declare a local variable of type `int` and then declare another variable of type `int*`. The pointer is then initialised with the address of `a` using the `&` operator.

You now have to understand that each variable is stored at it's address and has some value. That means that the variable `var` is stored at the address `&var` and has the value of what is stored in the bits at address `&var`. This applies to all variables, including pointers!

In the above example, variable `a` is stored at the address `&a` and has the value 10. The pointer `p` is stored at the address `&p` and has the value `&a`.

If you intend to use pointers like this you have to learn about scope and the lifetime of local variables.
For example, in the function below, `var` is a local variable. It is allocated on the stack only when the function is executed and after that it is popped.

```
void f()
{
    int var = 10;
    var = var + 5;
} // <-- scope of the function is exited. var is popped from the stack.
```

You can use pointers to hold the addresses of your local variables. However, you need to pay attention that if the scope is exited, variables defined in it no loger exist. Any pointer that held the address of those variables do not change their value, but will point to addresses that are used for something else. For example:

```
int main()
{
    int* p;

    // now we create a scope
    {
        int a = 10;
        p = &a;
    }

    // this is undefined behaviour.
    printf("%d", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

Even though the code will compile and run without error, it is not correct. If you run it, nothing will guarantee what the output will be because the address of `a` has been freed when the scope exited, and will be used to store other things on the stack.

Why does your first example crash? @Olaf Dietsche explained it in his answer.

Why does your second example not crash? It is similar to my last example. It will compile and run, but you have no guarantee on what will happen.